# Software to display 3D surfaces

Tags: math-software, 3d, surfaces, visualization

What are some examples of software or online services that can display surfaces that are defined implicitly (for example, the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$)?  Please add an example of usage (if not obvious).

Also, I'm looking for the following (if any):

- a possibility to draw many surfaces on the same sheet
- to show cross-sections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is a free online service that can draw implicit surfaces. It is essentially the same as the program [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), but with limited capabilties (for example, it is not able to plot more than one surface at a time).

This code will plot the unit sphere:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2+z^2==1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1}]
```

[Here is the output online](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot3D%5Bx%5E2%2by%5E2%2bz%5E2==1,%7Bx,-1,1%7D,%7By,-1,1%7D,%7Bz,-1,1%7D%5D), and here is a screen capture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you; I'll accept your answer. But I cannot display cylinder by ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2==1,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},{z,-10,10}].

Comment: @stannic Oh, now I can comment everywhere so I guess it is better to answer here: 

Try `ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2+z==1+z,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-10,10}]` (see the result: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot3D%5Bx%5E2%2by%5E2%2bz==1%2bz,%7Bx,-1,1%7D,%7By,-1,1%7D,%7Bz,-10,10%7D%5D )

Comment: In other words, the variable z should be included in the expression? Earlier I tried x^2+y^2+0z==1 without success.

Answer (score 2):

Try these for algebraic surfaces:

- [surf](http://surf.sourceforge.net/) generates excellent images.
- [surfer](http://www.imaginary2008.de/surfer)
- [surfex](http://www.surfex.algebraicsurface.net/)

from http://www.algebraicsurface.net/.

Comment: Thanks you but will it work under Windows?

Comment: @stannic, the last two claim that they work in Windows.

Comment: Surfer works but it seems to be rather slow.

Comment: @stannic, I think they do ray tracing... `surf` certainly does.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) can handle the first through the use of [ContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot3D.html). That reference page has the necessary syntax for all of what you are asking. By cross-sections I am assuming you are referring to $f(x,y,z) = k$ as $k$ varies? If so, that is done by just leaving off the `== k` in the function usage (see the documentation for more information).

Comment: I was referring to the intersection of the surface and an arbitrarily chosen plane.BTW, I use an online translator; English is not my native.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t comment eveywhere so I answer here :

> I cannot display cylinder by ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2==1,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},{z,-10,10}].

Try `ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2+z==1+z,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-10,10}]` (see [the result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot3D%5Bx%5E2%2by%5E2%2bz==1%2bz,%7Bx,-1,1%7D,%7By,-1,1%7D,%7Bz,-10,10%7D%5D)).

Comment: Yes, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use MATLAB. Or Maple if you like, Maple is easier than MATLAB.!

[Two plot or surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCV8q.png)

Comment: Is it possible to display surfaces (like sphere, ellipsoid etc.) in Maple? You have shown only plots.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [DataMelt mathematical computations](http://jwork.org/dmelt/) can plot graphs in 3D.
 As example, you can see the 3D graphs in [here](http://jwork.org/dmelt/examples/index.php?start=24)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux system and have no problem to build from source, I can recommend *asxp*, the *Algebraic Surface eXPlorer*.

It is a little program I wrote some time ago and are now in the process of polishing the code, making it available through GitHub:

[asxp_npr2](https://github.com/juergenboehm/asxp_npr2)

The following two pictures are from asxp:

[image]

This one is a torsal surface (note the straight lines in the crossfield of principal curvature directions):

[image]

For more details see [my asxp answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298484/21940).